# FFT from scilab is different than wolfram alpha

Tags: matlab, wolfram-alpha, fast-fourier-transform

I am getting completely different values of `FFT([1,2])` in scilab and Wolfram. I wondering what is going on and who is right.

```
Wolfram alpha: fft([1,2]):
{2.12132, -0.707107}
```

[Wolfram alpha output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1GFG.png)

```
Scilab fft([1,2]):
3.  -1.
```

[Scilab output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIYNo.png)

Comment: There are different definitions of the discrete Fourier transform that are normalized differently. Within a consistent definition, a change to the forward transform causes the opposite change to the inverse transform, so they still invert one another.

Comment: @someuser The ratio is the same.

Comment: I doubt that both numbers are exactly integers. Does Scilab round the result somehow (then it might be the same result, before the rounding)?

Comment: @PierreCarre You are right, didn't noticed that. When I compute in Wolfram `fft([1,2])*sqrt(2)` it's exactly the same as Scilab. But still do not understand why.

Comment: @Dirk No, they're integers in this convention; the first one is $1 \cdot e^0 + 2 \cdot e^0=3$ and the second one is $1 \cdot e^0+2 \cdot e^{\pi i}=-1$.

Comment: The values are certainly not *completely different*. They only differ by a factor $\sqrt2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the definition... Scilab is using
$$
X_k = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_ n e^{-i 2 \pi k n/N}, \quad k = 0, \cdots, N-1
$$

While Wolfram's default definition is

$$
X_k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_ n e^{-i 2 \pi k n/N}, \quad k = 0, \cdots, N-1
$$

If you want Wolfram to use the same definition, you must use the parameter "FourierParameters->{1,-1}". The general case in Wolfram ({a,b}) is

$$
X_k = \frac{1}{n^{(1-a)/2}}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_ n e^{i 2  b \pi k n/N}, \quad k = 0, \cdots, N-1
$$

Comment: Now, it's more clear :) `1/sqrt(N)` is about normalization?

Comment: @someuser1 Yes, as it was mentioned in a comment, the important thing is to define the inverse discrete Fourier transform in a compatible way.

Comment: @someuser1 In Wolfram's documentation they mention that {1,-1} is the usual convention in signal processing, while {1,-1} is the usual convention in data analysis. Their default is {0,1}.

Comment: @PierreCarre Sign error in your last comment.

Comment: @someuser1 See also https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FourierTransforms.html

Comment: @someuser1 With the `1/sqrt(N)` coefficient, the DFT preserves the 2-norm, which is useful for some applications. For the computation of Fourier series coefficients, you want the version with coefficient `1`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform

Comment: Thank you all so much!

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut you are correct, it should be {-1,1} in the case of data analysis.